# Frontend vs backend localization strategy comparison

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, sails.js, ionic-framework

I am developing an application based on Sails JS backend and Web and Mobile frontends. My plans for the frontend frameworks are:

- Web fronend - AngularJS + Bootstrap
- Mobile frontend - AngularJS + Ionic with later port from Apache Cordova

With regards to the above brief explanation, I have to add a localization feature to the application. And this is where my question arises - since both Sails JS and AngularJS support localization, which one to pick up for my project?

Theoretically, I can have:

1. complete backend localization - I will use build in Sails JS capabilities and will put all localized resources as json files to the backend
2. complete frontend localization - I could add AngularJS add-on and localize interfaces on the frontend or
3. mixing backend and frontend localizations.

I would appreciate it if people with more hands-on experience elaborate on the topic, considering application architecture, and give me some enlightenment for possible pros / cons of the available options.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer something like 1.

We are working on a pretty huge Angular.js SPA application that has i18n support as well. First we were using complete frontend localization (if I remember correct [this one](https://angular-translate.github.io/))

But when application got bigger and bigger, it became a hassle to manage i18n files, loading them into page (and you only need to load the needed strings because i18n file it is huge!) etc etc.

Also, user will change language rarely, it doesn't need to be dynamic, fast, two way bound or anything else. It's OK if we reload whole app.

So we thought why? We don't need i18n in frontend. We need i18n in our "app". Then, I wrote a build system on node.js, basically it is a preprocessor that parses all `*.html and *.js` files we have, extracts strings from them, looks them up using an i18n file, puts the localized string and creates copies of files per language count.

So basically, we create `n` apps instead of 1, all programmatically generated, each one is in a different language.

It works pretty well. When user changes language, we reload page and include another localized file set, and language is changed!

Sample source html file:

```
<header>@message("string.to.be.localized.1"i "{{name}}")</header>
```

Sample js file:

```
angular.module("app", [])
  .directive("x", function(i18n) {
    return {
      templateUrl: "@HTML/templates/a.html",
      link: function() { console.log(i18n("string.in.js", "Umut")); }
    }
  })
```

After compilation:

source.en.html

```
<header>Hello {{name}}</header>
```

source.tr.html

```
<header>Merhaba {{name}}</header>
```

sample.en.js

```
angular.module("app", [])
  .directive("x", function(i18n) {
    return {
      templateUrl: "/templates/a.en.html",
      link: function() { console.log("Hello {0}", "Umut")); }
    }
  })
```

sample.tr.js

```
angular.module("app", [])
  .directive("x", function(i18n) {
    return {
      templateUrl: "/templates/a.tr.html",
      link: function() { console.log("Merhaba {0}", "Umut")); }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Why did not you split sets and subsets of translatable words/sentences into JSON files so they can be easily edited when it comes to batch modify language sets with huge amount of words/sentences. For example "sample.tr.js" it does not seem much comfortable for that scenario. (if I understood correctly your example).

Answer (score 6):

I will prefer backend localization, since:

still i feel angular i18n is not mature enough to handle all use case for localization like no code translation(till angular 8). Till now its best
for static data but not for dynamic data(errors coming from server side). And if we are using placeholders, pluralization in our static data so its complex to
understand its translation file and cannot translate libraries like material, ng bootstrap,etc.

Where if we are using backend localization, maybe we won't tackle all these situation and hardly users are changing their locale so its ok to re-load the application one time (though with angular i18n still we would have to re-bootstrap the application at runtime)

Answer (score 4):

I prefer front-end localization.
On back-end you can throw any exception that contains exception code and explanation in English - these are for developers. On front-end you can use each JSON (or other) file for each language of localization based on codes, that you got from back-end or based on architecture logic of your front-end.

Why I find front-end localization better - because front-end is closer to User that back-end and you can provide him batch of your files with one file of localization of his language. Since front-end application can call several back-end operations in his one, or even calls from several services (both internal or external) the localization of messages is redundant because the User must get any understandable and user-loyal message (but not any like "could not insert data into a table" or "external server not answers") - you ignore that message and provide your one. More from that - back-end nowadays is written to contact with a lot of other services (not people) and localization is redundant here since each developer understands English.